# How to $select on events with delta?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph to get events.

I try to return selected fields on events. In this case, only `subject`.

```
GET /me/calendarview/delta?startdatetime=2018-02-04T18:00:00.000Z&enddatetime=2018-02-11T18:00:00.000Z&$select=subject
```

But this still returns all fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid `$select` isn't supported. From the [documentation](http://id=%22use-query-parameters-in-a-delta-query-for-calendar-view%22):

> #### Use query parameters in a delta query for calendar view
>
> - Include the `startDateTime` and `endDateTime` parameters to define a date/time range for your calendar view.
> - `$select` is not supported.